# How do you add a macron to a character in an NSString? via Unicode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, unicode, character

Objective-C iOS Programming:

I need to display a number like 8.33333 just as 8.3, with the three having a macron (repeating number symbol, a bar line) above it.  I have done some searching and have not found a solution to this.  I have found the encoding for [C/C++/Java source code being "\u0304"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/304/index.htm) and for [Unicode being "U+0304"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macron).  Is there a way that I can create an NSString from a Unicode character? And how would a create a Unicode character with a macron?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you need this in a "plain text" file, or in an HTML page?  If the latter, using the CSS style `text-decoration: overline` will look better than 8.3&#x0304; does.

Comment: As the tags alluded to Objective C iOS Programming, edited question to state the platform.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For combining characters such as U+0304, the string should contain the original letter followed by the combining character. For instance,

```
NSString *str = @"ca\u0304t";
```

is a representation of cāt.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Is there anyway for this to be applied across multiple characters/numbers without the seperation in the macron?

Comment: @michaellindahl You could use combining overline, U+0305, but it won’t look good on characters with different heights. Compare the following three examples: the first one uses combining macron and the latter two use combining overline: āāā, a̅a̅a̅, a̅b̅c̅.

Comment: Most fonts have all the digits the same height.